# Spacing around \amalg with KpFonts-otf

Tags: math-mode, spacing, kpfonts

The space around the symbol `\amalg` seems a little bit too big when using the OTF version of KpFonts. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\begin{document}

\( A_1 \cup A_2 \)

\( \bigcup_i A_i \)

\( A_1 \amalg A_2 \)

\( \coprod_i A_i \)

\( A_1 \sqcup A_2 \)

\( \bigsqcup_i A_i \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to slightly reduce this spacing (or shrink the symbol itself)?

Comment: The spacing is exactly the same for `\amalg` as for `\cup`, namely `\medmuskip` on either side.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for this information. Perhaps I should email the author of this font package to see if the symbol size can be reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing is the same around `\cup` and `\amalg`, that is, `\medmuskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\showoutput

\begin{document}

\( A \cup A \)

\( A \amalg A \)

\end{document}
```

An abridged version of the console output

```
....\mathon
....\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#2524
....\kern0.26
....\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22241 plus 1.1112 minus 2.22241
....\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#383
....\penalty 700
....\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22241 plus 1.1112 minus 2.22241
....\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#2524
....\kern0.26
....\mathoff
[...]
....\mathon
....\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#2524
....\kern0.26
....\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22241 plus 1.1112 minus 2.22241
....\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#728
....\penalty 700
....\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22241 plus 1.1112 minus 2.22241
....\TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#2524
....\kern0.26
....\mathoff
```

As you see, only the symbol changes.

If you want to scale down `\amalg`, you can define a new math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[range=\amalg,Scale=0.84625]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[range=]

\begin{document}

\sbox0{$\cup$}\the\wd0

\sbox0{$\amalg$}\the\wd0

\( A \cup A \)

\( A \amalg A \)

\end{document}
```

[image]